# Resetting Themes Folder to Default

Tags: themes

I recently unzipped a folder into my themes directory.  However unlike other themes this one was not contained in a top-level folder.  So it just dumped about 50 files directly into the themes folder.

Is there a way I can effectively reset the themes folder so I don't have all these excess files?

Otherwise I'm considering a fresh install.

Comment: Sort by file date delete the newest? Why do you think this is a WordPress question?

Comment: my files sort by mod date...there is group of Tnew and a group of Tnew+2 minutes...not sure if they are related....thought WP might have a reset button for this...a way to go back to just the default theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, WordPress does not manage your theme directory, and there is no reset function.

There are two important points you should learn from that experience:

1. Always test new software (themes and plugins) in a local installation. Do not just upload something you have not tested before.
2. You could manage the directory or your whole installation with a version control software like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). This way, you could reset the directory content to an earlier state, it would take just one command in a terminal. And some time to learn these tools, of course.